# Remove variant's size picture from slider - Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

We have a shopify store and we imported our product csv. It processed fine however we now see duplicate variant images for colors. Its basically duplicating the color variant images and showing the same color images for almost same number of size variants. While everything looks good in the Shopify dashboard, only the storefront is duplicating the variant images.

I have been struggling with Shopify support and they suggested manually removing the duplicate images which is huge task going through 17k variant images. We are hoping there is a way to fix this from the code. Please help.

Is there a way I can hide/remove the picture using liquide code of Shopify, or JS/CSS, Is it possible?

Here is the code of which is generating pictures.

```
{% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
<div class="flexslider product_gallery product-{{ product.id }}-gallery {% if product-images == blank %}product_slider{% endif %} {% if settings.product_thumbs == false %}animated fadeInUp{% endif %}">
  <ul class="slides">
    {% for image in product.images %}
      <li data-thumb="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}" data-title="{% if image.alt contains 'youtube' or image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}{{ product.title }}{% else %}{{ image.alt | escape }}{% endif %}">
        {% if image.alt contains 'youtube' or image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}
          {% assign src = image.alt | split: 'src="' %}
          {% assign src = src[1] | split: '"' | first %}

          {% if src contains '?' %}
            {% assign src = src | append: '&amp;autoplay=1' %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign src = src | append: '?autoplay=1' %}
          {% endif %}

          <div class="video-container {% if image.alt contains 'vimeo' %}vimeo{% else %}youtube{% endif %}">
            <div>
              <a href="{{ src }}" class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" data-fancybox-group="{{ product.id }}" title="{{ product.title | escape }}">
                {{ image.alt }}
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{{ image | product_img_url: 'master' }}" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="{{ product.id }}" title="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
            <img  src="{{ image | product_img_url: '1024x1024' }}"
                  alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}"
                  class="lazyload transition-in cloudzoom {% if featured_image.id == image.id %}featured_image{% endif %}"
                  data-image-id="{{ image.id }}"
                  data-index="{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                  data-cloudzoom="zoomImage: '{{ image | product_img_url: 'master' }}', tintColor: '{{ settings.shop_bg_color }}', zoomPosition: 'inside', zoomOffsetX: 0, touchStartDelay: 250"
                   />
          </a>
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Sanjeev! I'd love to take a deeper look into this as I know that variant images can be a pain - but can you post a picture or link to the site so I can get a better understanding of what you're talking about visually?

Currently, the code looks like it's functioning the way that it ought to be by bringing in every image associated to the product - but that doesn't seem to be what you want happening.

Comment: @RyanGreen thanks for looking in to it, here is the url: https://www.thestuffsquad.com/products/worlds-goodest-teacher-8

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like

```
 {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
    {% if option.name == "Color" %}
        {% capture colorCount %}
          {{ option.values.size }}
        {% endcapture %}
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

somewhere above your product code in order to get the number of color options you have. Then limit the display by the number of colors that you have. This is assuming that you're not going to want to show more images than colors.

Then where it says the following:

```
{% for image in product.images %}
```

add **limit: colorCount** to the end as a filter. This will make it so the liquid only shows enough images to cover the color count.

```
{% for image in product.images limit:colorCount %}
```

This is still somewhat of a hackfix, as I'm not entirely sure why those images are showing up - it may have been some strange column that went rampant as you were uploading your csv.

Hopefully this pushes you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @RyanGreen i am updating the code as you suggested and let you know it works